# progress bar not show remaining by percent when download file?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 8 I face issue progress bar not display
parts of download

suppose I download data then 20 percent then 40 percent until reach

to 100 percent but progress bar stop to 100 percent without show

what is remaining

what I try

```
this._dataService.PostUpload(this.selectedoptions.toString(),this.fileToUpload)
 .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  switch (event.type) {
    
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
      console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log('Upload successfully created!', event.body);
    
      FileSaver.saveAs(event.body, this.fileToUpload.name + '.xlsx')
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.progress = 0;
      }, 1500);

  }
})
```

html componet

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <span class="upload" *ngIf="progress > 0">
    {{progress}}%
  </span>
</div>
```

**Update Post**

I see `Uploaded! progress on console

but my issue it still stop on 100 percent and no changes

so what benefit from progress

I make progress to know that what remaining

see image below

[image: progress issue]

Comment: Are you seeing `"Uploaded! [progress]"` in the console? that will narrow it down to a problem getting the event, or a problem in rendering...

Answer (score -1):

To report progress events, you must set the [`reportProgress` option](https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress) to `true` when making the request.

Comment: i set it on service

Comment: How large is the file you are uploading? If it is very small, all progress will happen at once since the entire file is sent in a single packet.

Comment: file reach to 100 kb

Comment: i do service as below : PostUpload(selectedoptionsId, file):Observable<any>
{

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
  formData.append('selectedoptions',selectedoptionsId.toString());
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'DeliverySys/Upload', formData,{reportProgress: true,observe:'events', responseType: 'blob'});
}

Comment: This is a very small file; the transfer will happen more or less instantly with no progress to report in the middle. Try it with a 50MB file and see what happens?